# How to create a 2D array of a contructor (with 2 arguments) in spec file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This question is entirely related to unit testing in Angular with Jasmine and Karma.

I have one component called *Strip*. I have its template, its typescript, its configuration and its test case i.e. spec file.

**strip.config.ts**

```
// this is the configuration file for the StripComponent

import { WidgetSource } from '../../shared/models/widgetSource';

export class StripConfig {
    type: 'strip';
    rows: WidgetSource[][]; // <-------------- MY REQUIREMENT

    constructor() {}
}
```

This is the *WidgetSource* that the above config class has imported:

**widgetSource.ts**

```
/**
 * Widget Source class.
 */

import { DashboardName, WidgetName } from './myJSONConfig';

export class WidgetSource {
    dashboardName: DashboardName;
    widgetName: WidgetName;

    constructor(
        dashboardName: DashboardName,
        widgetName: WidgetName
    ) {
        this.dashboardName = dashboardName;
        this.widgetName = widgetName;
    }
}
```

Here's the spec file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { StripComponent } from './strip.component';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { StripConfig } from './strip.config';
import { WidgetSource } from 'src/app/shared/models/widgetSource';
import { DashboardName, WidgetName } from 'src/app/shared/models/myJSONConfig';

fdescribe('StripComponent', () => {
    let component: StripComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<StripComponent>;
    ...
    const strip: StripConfig = {
        type: 'strip',
        rows: new WidgetSource([DashboardName.MY_DASHBOARD], [WidgetName.HISTOGRAM]) // HELP
    };

    ...
});
```

If it was a single value like this in config:

`rows: WidgetSource;`

My code in spec file would be:

`rows: new WidgetSource(DashboardName.RPM_DASHBOARD, WidgetName.ACTIVE_DAYS_GRAPH)`

But my requirement is a double dimensional array. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize it like this:

```
const strip: StripConfig = {
  type: 'strip',
  rows:
    // open here the array
    [
      // array consists of arrays so open here first second level array
      [
        // initialize here the WidgetSources
        new WidgetSource([DashboardName.MY_DASHBOARD], [WidgetName.HISTOGRAM]),
        new WidgetSource([DashboardName.MY_DASHBOARD], [WidgetName.HISTOGRAM])
      ],
      // add more second level arrays if you need
      [
        new WidgetSource([DashboardName.MY_DASHBOARD], [WidgetName.HISTOGRAM]),
        new WidgetSource([DashboardName.MY_DASHBOARD], [WidgetName.HISTOGRAM])
      ]
    ]
};
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4BF0AsBGEKUAJgHIoC2wcA3gFByIQB2aMUArgjNABRhO%20JAEsEcFlWAAuOOygiWAcwCUtAL71N9UJFiJUGOAHURJJcBgVqdRszYduvKAKGjxk6rPmLVGrfQ64NDwyOiYpuaWAMoQnFAINAxMTCR4hMTkUrI4aAREpNbAANx2TADuZhZW2SZVlkWlZfbyTvzNKXBpeRmFtbn5mUUANB0plVE1XnWTRc0qtp2dMLgiaAB03YN9NgC8XekFWdSlSykra%20sT1UVw%209cNUqcpmpq6IQbhcNEcImAAwqwAGYiJSLFIIVitHj8QTCMRwKAQcpoWSRaqxeKJADaAF08Qt-NpIQ45L8wLIfgoAcDQXdwUiUdJmgB6FlwCBgYAsOC4YBQGgrGjEKAoACezWxYzZcBF4paaxgmAgQNlUFFYswaAgHK5PL5ArgIKg7DkwBJJDgSGAADdgEg1RqxlKzkwZYoRDARChRAAvGgGwV8mYYuIJYBoMZMFjAcohmJhxJ8GNxga9Y7APgAIjTRzgAEYsyphhJY-Gppms%20jLAWi8Wo6W49WYJjw8my7mhlJs53SHAAExFksp8tFbPNgd10ZnXHTpYylAkS2UaA0NDm1iW612h1yzVwESqsVxUvAEjOhsj5utpMj3sZnuHTK14uN0fdqv1eCFlT111v69E0zO8nx2St70nV8ry-MdP0mSC-yWXFmmQ9RiiAA) is working sample in TypeScript playground.

Comment: Error: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DashboardName'

Comment: I have updated my answer with live sample in TypeScript playground.

Comment: I'm looking into it. Will come back to you shortly. thanks.